# Finding value from given Matrix Equation

Tags: matrices

Let
$$A =  \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix} $$
And $$B =  \begin{bmatrix} p \\ q \\ \end{bmatrix} $$ which is not equal to null matrix.
Such that $$AB=B$$ and $$a + d =5050.$$ Find the value of $ad-bc.$

Comment: Do you know matrix multiplication.

Comment: I did multiply AB and equate it to B but after that I got 2 equation but I couldn't figure out how to find given expression value

Answer (score 3):

$AB=B$ tells you one of the eigenvalues of the matrix is $1$.

The trace of $A$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, which is also the sum of the diagonal entries. Thus, the sum of the eigenvalues is $a+d=5050$.

There are two eigenvalues, so the two eienvalues are $1,5049$.

The determiniant of $A$ is $ad-bc$ and is also the product of the eigenvalues, so it is $5049$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate that but at my level we are not taught eigenvalues. So can you give any other possible solution?

Comment: Done, as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know eigenvalues, you can rewrite $AB = B$ as $(A-I) B = 0$. Since $B \neq 0$, that means that $A-I$ must not be invertible (i.e. it has zero determinant). That is, $\det(A-I) = (a-1) (d-1) - bc = 0$.

Now expanding out the expression for the determinant, we see $(a-1)(d-1) - bc = ad-bc - (a+d) +1$. You know $a+d = 5050$, so you can solve for $ad-bc$.